# Error with super. in JAVA

Tags: java

I'm learning JAVA and currently I've got a problem with the use of super.
For some reason it displays an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems:     The field Animal.n is not visible   The field Animal.m is
>   not visible*

How do I fix it? I realize that String n and int m are set to private, as I am trying to utilize the "super.". Thank you in advance. The part of the code below i'm having problem with is the "super(n,m)

```
public class Zoo 

{

public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Animal[] cat= new Animal[5];
    BigAnimal big = new BigAnimal("Roro",20,true,true);

    cat[0] = new Animal ("Mauie",5,true);
    cat[1] = new Animal ("Frankie",7,false);
    cat[2] = new Animal ("Zo-Zo",8,false);
    cat[3]=  new Animal ("Alice",12,true);
    cat[4]= big;

    System.out.println(cat[0].getName());
    System.out.println(cat[0].something(10));

  }



}

class Animal

{

    private String n;
    private int m;


    public Animal(String name,int meals, boolean doesitbite)

    {
        n=name;
        m=meals;
    }

}

class BigAnimal extends Animal

{
     boolean doesitlove;

     public BigAnimal (String name, int meals, boolean doesitbite, boolean doesitlove) 
        {

            super(n,m);
            doesitlove=true;
        }

}
```

Comment: `Animal` has no constructor taking just 2 parameters.

Comment: *"The line that is wrong(?) is bolded in the code below."* No, it isn't.  *"The part in the code below is bolded, as I've mentioned"* No, it isn't, as I've mentioned. :-)

Comment: Replace `super(n,m);` with `super(name, meals, doesitbite);`

Comment: Thanks Hugues! Works like a charm now (I guess) :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor for `BigAnimal`, change

```
super(n,m);
```

to

```
super(name, meals)
```

That is, pass the values given to `BigAnimal` constructor to the superclass constructor.

Also, fix your bug(?) and either give the super class a constructor with just two parameters or pass a 3rd parameter to the constructor you've got.  E.g.,

```
super(name, meals, doesitbite)
```

Comment: Good answer, but I'm not gonna up-vote it, because that would prevent OP from deleting the question. The question is of no use to others, so it should be deleted.